# How do I separate the cards more in my project

Tags: html, css

How can I separate the cards in my project; I am new to HTML and am still learning so I don't know how to do this. I don't like how the cards are right up next to each other; is there any way I can fix this?

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.shell {
  height:65vh;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: auto;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  align-items: center; /* Added */
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  
}

.gameshell{
  height:65vh;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: auto;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  align-items: center; /* Added */
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid #EF9A9A;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card-header {
  color: #D32F2F;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EF9A9A;
  background-color: #FFEBEE;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.card-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.material-icons {
  font-size: 36px!Important;
  color: #D32F2F;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.main-description {
  color: #D32F2F;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFEBEE;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EF9A9A;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: #D32F2F;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #dfd5d7;
  color: #942626;
}

.header a.active {
  background-color: #D32F2F;
  color: #FFEBEE;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
      <link rel="icon" type="png" href="/images/icon.png"/>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <title>Project-LuLo</title>
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="header">
  <a href="#home" class="logo">Project-LuLo</a>
  <div class="header-right">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#games">Games</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gameshell">
      <a href="#test"class="card">
    <div class="card-header">place_holder</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">null</i>
      <div class="main-description">place_holder</div>
    </div>
  </a>
          <a href="#test"class="card">
    <div class="card-header">place_holder</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">null</i>
      <div class="main-description">place_holder</div>
    </div>
  </a>
          <a href="#test"class="card">
    <div class="card-header">place_holder</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">null</i>
      <div class="main-description">place_holder</div>
    </div>
  </a>
          <a href="#test"class="card">
    <div class="card-header">place_holder</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">null</i>
      <div class="main-description">place_holder</div>
    </div>
  </a>
          <a href="#test"class="card">
    <div class="card-header">place_holder</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">null</i>
      <div class="main-description">place_holder</div>
    </div>
  </a>
          <a href="#test"class="card">
    <div class="card-header">place_holder</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">null</i>
      <div class="main-description">place_holder</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems like a good use case for CSS grid. I encourage you to explore it - [here is a good starting point](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of duplicated and unnecessary code. Try removing it.
To increase the gap between div elements you can use the `gap` property.

Check out the docs [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap#:%7E:text=The%20gap%20CSS%20property%20sets,%2Dgap%20and%20column%2Dgap%20.)

```css
  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.shell {
  height: 65vh;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: auto;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  align-items: center;
  /* Added */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gameshell {
  height: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  /*newly added*/
  margin: 5px 20px;
  align-items: center;
  /* Added */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid #EF9A9A;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card-header {
  color: #D32F2F;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EF9A9A;
  background-color: #FFEBEE;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.card-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.material-icons {
  font-size: 36px!Important;
  color: #D32F2F;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.main-description {
  color: #D32F2F;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFEBEE;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EF9A9A;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: #D32F2F;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #dfd5d7;
  color: #942626;
}

.header a.active {
  background-color: #D32F2F;
  color: #FFEBEE;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#home" class="logo">Project-LuLo</a>
  <div class="header-right">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#games">Games</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gameshell">
  <a href="#test" class="card">
    <div class="card-header">place_holder</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">null</i>
      <div class="main-description">place_holder</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#test" class="card">
    <div class="card-header">place_holder</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">null</i>
      <div class="main-description">place_holder</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#test" class="card">
    <div class="card-header">place_holder</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">null</i>
      <div class="main-description">place_holder</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#test" class="card">
    <div class="card-header">place_holder</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">null</i>
      <div class="main-description">place_holder</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#test" class="card">
    <div class="card-header">place_holder</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">null</i>
      <div class="main-description">place_holder</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#test" class="card">
    <div class="card-header">place_holder</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">null</i>
      <div class="main-description">place_holder</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: please formulate your answers as answers, not as comments. Read [answer]

Comment: yea I know that but as the question is not that clear, so I mentioned to treat this as comment because some users downvote or report it.

Comment: well your answer is helpful and formulated well, which is refdlectd in the upvotes. describing it as a comment could also get it reported. keep up the effort ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try grid for making layouts like this, it comes quite handy.

But right now I am guessing you are learning flex.

There are two ways you can do this.

**First:** the flex way

```
gap: 10px;
```

the gap property is actually quite great. It works just like its literal meaning. It produces a gap between your flex childs, Horizontally and vertically too.

**Second:** the css way

```
.card{
    margin: 10px; //quite simple actually :)
}
```

try gap though (works with grid too)